# Finding the Area Under a Curve

Tags: integration

I am learning about finding the area under a curve and was wandering what $dy$ had to with it.  When finding the area under a curve you want the anti-derivative, so you get $\int f(x)dx$ but if $F'(x) = f(x)$ then would $f(x) = \frac{dy}{dx}$? If this is correct (if not please explain where I made a mistake(s)) then $f(x)dx = dy$.  How does $\int dy$ result in the area under the curve of $f(x)$?

Comment: Under which curve: $y=f(x)$ or $y=F(x)$?

Comment: under the curve of f(x)

Comment: Then, according to what you said yourself, $f(x)=y$, **not** "$F(x)=y$". And therefore, to reiterate: $f(x)=y$, **not** "$f(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}$".

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

I think you are trying to understand the fundamental theorem of calculus, which says, in a way, that there are two equivalent ways to find the area under a curve. One si by calculating a definite integral as a limit of sums, the other is by finding an antiderivative.

Here are two links that might help.

[Proof that the area under a curve is the definite integral, without the fundamental theorem of calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226732/proof-that-the-area-under-a-curve-is-the-definite-integral-without-the-fundamen/2226894#2226894)

[Why can't the second fundamental theorem of calculus be proved in just two lines?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991575/why-cant-the-second-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-be-proved-in-just-two-lines/1991585#1991585)

(Marking as community wiki since it's not really an answer, but may point to one.)